# How to add blur effect to dock in Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME

Tags: customization, dock, ubuntu-dock

I want to add blur to dock like the MacOS dock. Trying to get this MacOS blur dock effect:

[image: screen]

Comment: Could you provide an example of the effect that you want to achieve? Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)) Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Gonna add the pic

Answer (score 1):

There is a Shell extension called `Blur My Shell` where you can choose what parts of your shell you want to blur, and how blurry you want them!
[Blur My Shell](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3193/blur-my-shell/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [the dock doesn't support background blur on GNOME](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/224) (the functionality is just isn't there). See the linked issue for more information.

You can however, apply the [blur effect to the top panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCbAX.png) or [Dash To Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) (an extension which transforms the panel into a dock) using [Blyr](https://github.com/yozoon/gnome-shell-extension-blyr)* which is an extension which adds blur effect to the panel and/or the overview.

This is how it looks like with dash-to-panel**:
[image]

Not quite what you wanted but that's all available right now, as far as I know.

**You need to download the extension from the repository itself and install it manually as the update still hasn't appeared on the extensions site.*

***It isn't true blur but it works nevertheless. There are some caveats obviously, for example you can't position the panel to the bottom as it's intended to keep it on top and it looks bad with some shell-themes like Flat Remix.*

Comment: Alright thanks ! Though there was a video for showing the blur effect on dock and stuff but it's not a tutorial

Comment: There is now a feature to move it to the bottom